# Show or hide a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0

Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swap(val) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('tablepanel');
        if (val == 0) {

            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
             }
        else {
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
</script>
```

.aspx code

```
  <div id="tablepanel" runat="server" >
                                             <table style="width: 901px; height: 22px;">
                                             <tr>
                                                  <td align="left">
                                                           <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Height="28px" OnClick="btnBack_Click" 
                                                             Style="cursor: pointer;" Text="&lt;&lt; Prev" ToolTip="Previous Question" 
                                                             UseSubmitBehavior="false" Width="75px" />
                                                   </td>
                                                  <td align="center">
                                                             <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Height="28px" OnClick="btnSave_Click" 
                                                               Style="cursor: pointer;" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save Answer" 
                                                                                        UseSubmitBehavior="false" Width="75px" />
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="right">
                                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Height="28px" OnClick="btnNext_Click" 
                                                                                        Style="cursor: pointer;" Text="Next &gt;&gt;" ToolTip="Next Question" 
                                                                                        UseSubmitBehavior="false" Width="75px" />
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        </div>
```

cs code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "BodyOnLoadScript",
                  string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">swap({0});</script>", 0), false);
```

Brief code,i am not able to hide and show the div .Can anyone help me resolve the error thank you.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Thanks for all answer..i found this code works fine for the simple div(which doesn't contain any button).But for my case buttons and table are there.i required answer for these case.

Answer (score 0):

```
function swap(val) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('<%= tablepanel.ClientID %>');
        if (val == 0) {

            elem.style.display = 'none'; 
             }
        else {
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ClientID` as the id of server controls is changed when html is generated by asp.net If you have framework 4 and above you can use `ClientIDMode="static"` to keep the server id unchanged on client end.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('<%= tablepanel.ClientID %>');
```

As a additional note elem.style.visibility keeps the space event its hidden you can use elem.style.display property if you reclaim the space when its hidden

```
elem.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **display**  property..

```
       if (val == 0) {

            elem.style.display = 'none'; 
             }
        else {
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery function inside function,

```
function swap(val) {
        var elem = $('#table_id');
        if (val == 0) {

            elem.hide('slow'); 
             }
        else {
            elem.show('slow');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the div doesn't have to run at server, you should remove `runat="server"`. This will have a little cost for server. If you do use this element in server side, you can use ClientID just like Rituraj and Adil said.

```
<div id="tablepanel" >
```